# Replacing a string with pdo on MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, pdo, replace

I want to replace a string but I use PDO. Whatever I have tried is not working. Have you ever replaced a mysql string by using PDO connection?

Here is an example which is not working.

```
try
{
    $image = $_POST['data1'];
    $id= $_POST['data2'];


    $insert = "UPDATE myTable SET images=REPLACE(images,':image','') where id = :id";

    $insertStmt = $conn->prepare($insert);
    $insertStmt->bindValue(":image", $image);
    $insertStmt->bindValue(":id", $id);

        $insertStmt->execute();

        echo "success";
}

        catch(PDOException $ex)
{
        echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write :image instead of ':image'

```
$insert = "UPDATE myTable SET images=REPLACE(images,:image,'') where id = :id";
```

Comment: Explainer: The PDO driver takes care of quoting so adding your own manual quotes actually breaks things.